# update content of div without jquery in nodejs-express handlebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I know how to change the content of a div tag with JQuery, but now I want to know that if I don't want to use JQuery, can I change the content of loginDiv tag? I am not sure how I can set the value of div tag loginDiv with a response of router.post. can you help me is it possible or if I want to have a page without refresh the page I need to use Jquery?

I am using NodeJS express handlebar.

index.hbs:

```
<div  class="col-md-10">
                            <div id="loginDiv"></div>
                            <form role="form" action="/login" method="post" name="login"  onsubmit="return validateLoginForm()">
                                <fieldset>                          
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="username" class="font-weight-bold">Email</label>
                                        <input type="email" name="username" id="username" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="YourEmail@domain.com">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="passwordlogin" class="font-weight-bold">Password</label>
                                        <input type="password" name="passwordlogin" id="passwordlogin" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="div-padding">
                                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Sign In">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Forget?</button>
                                    </div>
                                </fieldset>
                            </form> 
                        </div>
```

index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
router.post('/login',function(req, res, next) {
  // How to write something in loginDiv
});
```

Comment: Since you're using server side handle bars, you can use handle bar config to set the text on the server before sending to the browser. jQuery is only inside browser. In browser you can create an ajax request to load data and set the div content without refreshing.

Comment: @XPD: So you mean we cannot set any content directly and I need to use only jquery to set the post value

Comment: You use [server-side templating](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html). Call `res.render("view file", data)` and use `data` in your view file to fill it dynamically.

Comment: Since you are using handlebars,  you can set the value of this div using it in post. See https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @ChrisG: It won't refresh the screen?

Comment: @XPD: can I use res.locals ?

Comment: It's not about refreshing the screen; the express view engine you're using allows you to insert data into the HTML you send back  to the browser. It that isn't what you're looking for, you need to exactly describe what you want to do, and why.

Comment: @ChrisG: I want to show a message if login was sucessful in loginDiv or show the error related to login.

Comment: Did you even look at my previous comments? How many times do I have to tell you how to do this? Use server side templates; use `res.render()`.

Comment: @ChrisG: I tried it by res.render("index", {textbody: textbody}); and it is working but now my problem is that page getting refresh and those I entered previously disappear. so is there any way to change the content without refresh the page?

Comment: @Amir Yes, of course: client-side JavaScript. The only way there is.

Answer (score 0):

Changing values in vanilla javascript can be easly done using document.innerHTML

```js
//to replace the content:
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = "<p>Yay! a paragraph!</p>"

//to ADD content: 
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML += "<p>Yay! Another paragraph!</p>"
```

Comment: Do I need to add any package?

Comment: The question title is misleading, the question is actually about server-side templates.

Answer (score -1):

You can always revert to innerHTML, if you know the HTML string is valid.

```
document.getElementById('loginDiv').innerHTML = "<b>Hello, World!</b>";
```

Comment: are u sure in nodejs in my router I can direct access to my document? I afriad I can.

Comment: No you can't. The question title is misleading, the question is actually about server-side templates.

Comment: @ChrisG: I would appreciate if u suggest a title so I can edit it.

Comment: @Amir I'd love to, but you have to clarify what you mean by "update" first.